# Lombok lazy getter for mutable collections

Tags: java, collections, lombok

I have a class which has a collection:

```
public class Foo
{
    @Inject
    private BarManager barManager;
    @Getter(lazy = true)
    private final List<Bar> bars = barManager.getAll();

    public void addBar(Bar bar)
    {
        bars.add(bar);
    }
}
```

However I cannot add/remove elements to/from the `List`. The cause is that the attribute is an `AtomicReference`. The warning/error is:

```
The method add(Employee) is undefined for the type  AtomicReference<AtomicReference<List<Employee>>>
```

How can perform add/remove operations on the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is weird indeed and depends on some implementation details. Moreover it break with NPE if the field hasn't been initialized yet. The proper solution works always:

```
getBars().add(bar);
```

Comment: I actually never thought of calling the getter. Sometimes the solution isn't that difficult. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer: This answer and especially the comments are here for informational purposes. Please use the accepted answer above instead of this.**

---

Wouldn't have thought to solve it so quickly by myself. The solution is rather weird:

```
public class Foo
{
    @Inject
    private BarManager barManager;
    @Getter(lazy = true)
    private final List<Bar> bars = barManager.getAll();

    public void addBar(Bar bar)
    {
        bars.get().get().add(bar);
    }
}
```

The `get()` returns the reference, however for some reason I have to call `get()` twice.

Comment: In the future we plan to change the implementation of the generated code for lazy getters to no longer use AtomicReference-s. So you shouldnot depend on it, and use getBars() instead. Disclaimer: I am one of the Project Lombok developers.

Comment: We do no longer have concrete plans to change this. That does not change the fact that you should just use `getBars()`, and not depend on internal behavior.

Comment: The current implementation no longer generates the double AtomicReference. Use the getter. But If you must, currently, if `bars.get() == bars` you should replace it by `null`. We use `null` to state uninitialized, and `bars` to mask null.